# ERROR adding basemap using ArcMap 10

Tags: arcmap, error

[image: NVIDIA OpenGL driver error]

When I have to use Bing Map Aerial as basemap in ArcMap 10, I get an NVIDIA error, then the main page closes down. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error you reported, I would start troubleshooting by updating your NVIDIA graphics driver.

1. Find the "Device Manager" on your system
2. Locate your NVIDIA device in the drop down lists
3. Right click on the icon, select "Update Driver Software..."
4. Just to be safe, do a Windows update

Best of luck!